# How do I rotate the contents of a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview

I have made a very simple web browser app using a web view.  Now I need to get the app so that when the iPhone is rotated, the text of the page is rotated as well.

How do I do this?

I am very confused by the auto-resize dialog, so it is possible I have done something wrong there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify?  Do you want the content of the WebView to autorotate so when the user turns the phone the content stays right-side-up?  Or do you want the content to rotate with the phone, so the user can turn the content sideways, upside-down, etc.  I can't tell which you mean from your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you sholud rotate UIWebView widget, not its contents. Contents should rotate as well. To support rotating add following code to your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
        return YES;
}
```

Rotated widget might look different then expected. Adjust struts and springs in Interface Builder.

Comment: i have done that, the text stays in portrait what are struts and springs?  I really cant understand the autosize box in interface builder

Comment: UIWebView is a UIView and not a UIViewController subclass and won't get sent shouldAutorotate

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give us some sample code in order to determine what goes wrong. It is as Jacek says, the only think you should need to do is to support auto rotation on the UIWebView itself. The content should be rotated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by device orientation and view frame.

In most cases UIViews do change with respect to the orientation change. But to clarify - it is not because of the orientation change, but the layout change.

Only UIViewControllers need to consider device orientation - UIViews do NOT. When the device orientation changes, the UIViewController captures the event from its instance methods:

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

The UIViewController then re-layout the views - leading to reframing of the UIViews. In many cases, iOS can helps you in simplifying the relayout process by setting the UIViewAutoresizeMask. For example:

```
myWebview.autoresizeMask = UIVIewAutoresizeMaskFlexibleHeight | UIVIewAutoresizeMaskFlexibleHeight;
```

implies that when webview's superview changed its bounds, the webview will change accordingly.

As a summary, UIView only takes care of its frame / bounds etc.